# Previous Day Variable in a Batch File

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, dos

I need to write a batch file that call a command and passes a date parameter for the previous day.

Example:

[function] CCYYMMDD

I can't seem to find any example of this. And my company doesn't like us to use freeware so I really need the solution to be a purely DOS based solution.

Comment: I came across some batch-based nastiness which did exactly this a while ago (it was a script for rotating Apache log files on Win32 if you want to do some Googling yourself) - I will see if I can dig it out for you. What Win version is it for? I seem to remember I had to modify it to get it to work on 2K3...

Comment: I have just remembered why I had to modify it, it's because the `date` command outputs the date in different formats depending on the system localisation settings - is this for one machine or many with potentially different settings?

Comment: Perhaps it's a silly question, but... If your company doesn't like you to use free software and one of you comes up with a batch script of their own, are they obliged to sell it to the company before using it?

Comment: lol, no they would concider the batch script as their property since it was created while performing my daily tasks. The own all intellecual rights to what employees and crontractors create.

Answer (score 2):

You could start with [Dostips: Date and Time](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsDateTime.php)
There are functions to evaluate a date to a serial day count and vice versa.
So it's results to

```
call :jdate "%date%" JD_result
set /a prev_day=JD_result-1
call :jdate2date %prev_day% YYYY MM DD
echo Previous day is %DD%.%MM%.%YYYY%
```

Comment: I received the following error: The system cannot find the batch label specified - jdate

Comment: It could be a good idea to copy the functions from dostips into your batch file

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the original solution I had for this but I found [something over at Rob Van Der Woude's site](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/yesterday_nt.txt) that will do the job nicely.

There is a bug in the file posted there, due the the fact that `SET /A` will treat strings that start with a zero as octal, and this causes problems when day/month dates start with a zero.

If you get the files linked above, but change the code of the :JDate procedure (line 157) to:

```
SET MonthChecker1=%2
SET MonthChecker2=%MonthChecker1:~0,1%
IF %MonthChecker2%==0 (
  SET MonthChecker3=%MonthChecker1:~1,1%
) ELSE (
  SET MonthChecker3=%MonthChecker1%
)
SET DayChecker1=%3
SET DayChecker2=%DayChecker1:~0,1%
IF %DayChecker2%==0 (
  SET DayChecker3=%DayChecker1:~1,1%
) ELSE (
  SET DayChecker3=%DayChecker1%
)
SET /A Month1 = ( %MonthChecker3% - 14 ) / 12
SET /A Year1  = %1 + 4800
SET /A JDate  = 1461 * ( %Year1% + %Month1% ) / 4 + 367 * ( %MonthChecker3% - 2 -12 * %Month1% ) / 12 - ( 3 * ( ( %Year1% + %Month1% + 100 ) / 100 ) ) / 4 + %DayChecker1% - 32075
FOR %%A IN (Month1 Year1) DO SET %%A=
GOTO:EOF
```

This is tested and working on a 2K8R2 box. It is definitely worth using this over other solutions out there, as it has the capability to determine what the date format on the host system is from the registry, which no other solution I have found does.

Comment: To solve the octal problem you could also use `set /a Month=1%Month% %% 100`, it always prefix te number with `1` and the modulo removes it in a safe way