# Trying to get batch to rename files being archived with previous date - no experience or knowledge

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to resolve a pain in the ass task in work by creating a batch file that will archive and rename an array of files with one click.

Currently I've got that, and it works fine after some Google help.

There are files that require to be renamed with the previous days date. I've looked thoroughly and found several examples which mean nothing to me, as I have not a clue what I'm doing.

These systems are locked down really tight, and the best I can do is a batch, nothing else. Is there a batch solution for this?

So an example of the archive and rename code I'm using is the simple:

```
copy "H:\My Documents\test\test.txt" "H:\My Documents\test\output\test.txt"
```

ren "H:\My Documents\test\output\test.txt" "%date:/=-%.txt"

So that works fine.

I saw this example:

```
    @echo off
if /i "%Date:~0,3%"=="Sun" ( call :DaysAgo 2 ) else (
    if /i "%Date:~0,3%"=="Mon" ( call :DaysAgo 1 ) else ( call :DaysAgo 1 )
)
echo %Year% %Month% %Day%
```

and thought that might be able to be stuck in somewhere, but it doesn't do anything, so the chances are I'm completely failing to understand how to deploy this bit of code.

Any help greatly appreciated, but I don't know programming, I don't know batch and so anything other than 'hi' will probably lose me in terms of understanding!! :)

Thanks,

Cal

Comment: First: the code in your example is language dependent and might not run as intended on your computer. Second: the `call` command calls another part of the script (you can think of it like a subroutine), which does the work. (there should be a part that starts with `:DaysAgo`)

Comment: So, you're trying to copy files and rename them with a date and... you have code which copies files and renames them with a date and it "works fine" - isn't that enough? What's the extra code supposed to do for you? If you need it to pick up multiple files, what are the conditions for it to pick?

Comment: Sorry, it's the way I've written the original text. It has two parts. The first part is the copying and renaming of files to the CURRENT date, which works fine. I cannot figure out how to get it to rename to the previous days date though and I have to do those renames manually. The code is worked very simply. I simply have a `COPY` and `REN` for each file I want, manually directed to the relevant files and folders. - Stephan, I have nothing like that, I'm really just podging together bits from examples and hoping it works. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

to get yesterday's date, you can use

```
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`"powershell (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')"`) do set yesterday=%%a
echo %yesterday%
copy "H:\My Documents\test\test.txt" "H:\My Documents\test\output\%yesterday%.txt"
```

As you can see, you can easily adapt the date format to your needs.

I used the code from [npocmaka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29814385/2152082)

Comment: So I simply run the batch as: `for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`"powershell (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')"`) do set yesterday=%%a echo %yesterday% copy "H:\My Documents\test\test.txt" "H:\My Documents\test\output\%yesterday%.txt" `  - That copies the file but the name is blank?

Comment: pay attention to the different styles of quotes (there are three different ones). Best just copy the line from above.

Comment: Are you on WinXP? Powershell is not installed by default at XP.

Comment: Yes, sorry, should probably have highlighted that. I'm on XP. We are upgrading to 8.1 this month though along with new systems.

Comment: If you can't (or don't want to) install Powershell on XP, the answers of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7065969/2152082) might be helpful.